# XmlSerializer WebResponse

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have this XML with many names, like a list:

```
<apelidos>
    <apelido>Casmilo</apelido>
    <apelido>Castro</apelido>
</apelidos>
```

And I did my model like this:

```
namespace IdCel.Model
{
   [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
   public class apelidos
   {
       [XmlArray("apelidos")]
       [XmlArrayItem("apelidos")]
       public List<apelido> apelidosNomes { get; set; }

       public apelidos()
       {
           apelidosNomes = new List<apelido>();
       }
   }

   public class apelido
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "apelido")]
       public string apelidoNome { get; set; }
   }
}
```

And my XmlSerializer

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(objetoLista.GetType());

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
var result = ser.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());

return result;
```

But it's not working, I do the same code with XML without list and it's working fine

Comment: what is the error  you get?

Comment: Doesn't have error, only not unserializer the XML!

Comment: The XmlArrayItem is referencing 'apelidos', shouldn't it be 'apelido'? Also, in that case, your class apelido, should either put XmlText on the apelidoNome or you could use a list of strings instead of the special class ;)

Comment: @user1887732: How complete is the XML you are giving here?  Also, instead of using var here for result, maybe you could make it a bit more friendly for us, and show the type you are expecting it to be?

Comment: Icepickle, I tried this:
`code
[XmlArray("apelidos")]
[XmlArrayItem("apelido")]
public List<string> apelido { get; set; }
`
but it's not worked too.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to read the contents of the `apelido` tags, you are much faster when you are using [Linq To XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb387098.aspx). For example:

```
var xml = @"<apelidos>
                <apelido>Casmilo</apelido>
                <apelido>Castro</apelido>
            </apelidos>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var apelidos = from apelido in doc.Descendants("apelido")
               select apelido.Value;
```

This gives you an `IEnumerable<string>` as result containing all the names.

EDIT: To load the XML from the web you can do the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
var doc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: How can I get my online XML with this way?

Comment: I did this, but my return is not a "apelido" list, right?

Comment: Exactly. As I said it's an `IEnumerable<string>`. To get a list of apelido objects you need to do the following: `var apelidos = (from a in doc.Descendants("apelido") select new apelido { apelidoNome = a.Value }).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Now It's worked!
I did this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class apelidos
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("apelido")]
    public List<string> apelido { get; set; }
}
```

And this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
           as HttpWebRequest;

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(objetoLista.GetType());

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        var result = ser.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());

        return result;
```